# Tridion Developer Summit 2015

Tags: discussion

I missed the 2014 Tridion Developer Summit and don't want to miss out this year.
When will the conference date be announced and where will it be held?

Comment: Unofficially I heard 14-15 September in Amsterdam

Comment: Mid September in Amsterdam.  Either the week of 14 or 21 Sept.  Still confirming venue, so dates not specific yet.

Comment: There's also going to be a "Developer day" at Innovate San Francisco in May - not the same thing, but kinda.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 2nd Tridion Developer Summit will be held on 16-17 September in Amsterdam at The Eye Film Museum.

We'll have 3 tracks for 2 days, including content on SDL Web 8 (Tridion 2015) and also DD4T.

Day 1 is focussed on the new version of SDL and also other products such as Media Manager and Smart Target.  We also have technical sessions on the Tridion Core service and the Alchemy GUI Extension framework.

Day 2 is focussed on Content Delivery and DD4T, with more than 4 long talks on DD4T, including running DD4T on .NET vNext and also deploying to Azure.

It's possible to attend 1 or both days.

See the full agenda here and also register here:

http://2015.tridiondevelopersummit.com/2015/home/home/#agenda

Answer (score 0):

Please also note that adjacent to the 2015 Tridion Developer Summit, SDL is having an open house, called SDL Community Open:

Register to attend the [Free SDL Open Community Days](https://community.sdl.com/events/sdl_community_open_sept_2015_amsterdam/c/e/63) with SDL R&D and PM!  [Monday for Business Users](https://community.sdl.com/events/sdl_community_open_sept_2015_amsterdam/c/e/62) and [Tuesday for Developers](https://community.sdl.com/events/sdl_community_open_sept_2015_amsterdam/c/e/63). Learn about [building sites with DXA on Tuesday](https://community.sdl.com/events/sdl_community_open_sept_2015_amsterdam/c/e/74) (paid). Have dinner on SDL at the [Architects Dinner Tuesday Night](https://community.sdl.com/events/sdl_community_open_sept_2015_amsterdam/c/e/66).